# SharePoint MOSS 2007: extranet's external FBA login stops working, can't trace cause

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have an extranet site. The Central Admin server is internal, with an external DMZ server that hosts the extended site. The external site connects to LDAP via FBA.

Every so often, the login.aspx page comes up without any core.css formatting or fonts, and users are unable to log in. When they try to submit their login they're re-prompted.

What has worked in the past is overwriting the web.config (containing connections to our LDAP server) with a known good copy. Recently, in addition to the overwrite, we've had to run an IISRESET.

The "default" internal site, connected to the local domain, works fine and without interruption.

The web.config 'fix' worked for a couple years, but recently it has been happening more frequently, almost daily. Last time it occurred, I noted that the 'bad' web.config's Modify date hadn't changed. A file compare shows them to be identical.

Has anyone seen something like this before? The only site customizations are the standard web.config connections to LDAP.

Much thanks,

Scott